# Additional markdown style in GitLab

Tags: gitlab

How can I add additional "markdown" style (like org file with org-ruby) to gitlib?

The "Advanced Setup Tips" are very vague about it and "github-markup gem readme" does also not really help. E.g. I installed org-ruby, but org files are not rendered like on github.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was an update in the last release notes that they actually went closer to the markdown spec and dropped parts of the individual flavor:

https://about.gitlab.com/2014/02/21/markdown-newline-behaviour/

This post might be a good idea to ask about additional formats